# How to set an attachFile folder in cypress-file-upload

Tags: cypress

In my tests I download the file first, then upload it further. By using `cypress-file-upload` I faced an issue that file can be uploaded only from `fixtures` folder. The question is how to upload the file from `downloads` folder?
I tried just to add `downloads` in front of the file name but it doesn't work.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="dropzone"]')
            .attachFile('downloads/img.png', {subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' });
```

> A fixture file could not be found at any of the following paths:
>
> cypress/fixtures/downloads/img.png

Comment: Have you tried using absolute paths. eg. for mac it could be like `/Users/JohnPix/Downloads/img.png` and for Windows `C:\Users\JohnPix\Downloads\img.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a relative path

```js
.attachFile('../downloads/img.png'
```